# How to do ordering of feature files

Tags: api, karate, cucumber-junit

Can someone please help me out, like how can I do ordering of my feature file and how can I run all of them at the same time. Eg; I have 50 feature files (Feature: abc, Feature: opq, Feature: mno and Feature: xyz) and I want to run feature files in below sequence:

1. Feature:mno
2. Feature: opq
3. Feature: xyz and
4. Feature: abc

I tried from my side by putting order like;
(Order=1)
Feature: mno
Some scenario

(Order=2)
Feature: opq
Some scenario

(Order=3)
Feature: xyz
Some scenario

(Order=4)
Feature:abc
Some scenario, but it doid not work for me.

Comment: if the answer in the linked question does not satisfy your needs, kindly assume that this is not supported by karate, and look for some other framework (or contribute code)